# chrome object properties undefined for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a small extension and getting a stuck with chrome object - all properties of them such storage, extension etc. are undefined when I try to access them from content script.
[image]

Here's the `permissions` part of the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
"storage",
"tabs",
"webRequest",
"*://*/*"
   ]
```

I can use `chrome.storage` in my options page, but I cannot access it in content script. This is strange for me, because

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:
>
> Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
> extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )
>
> runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
>
> storage

So it seemed I should have access to the `storage`, but I still haven't. What can be the reason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963414/3928095

Comment: Make sure not to set breakpoints *before* the first access to `chrome`, otherwise you'll hit https://crbug.com/754976

Comment: @wOxxOm, yes, it was the reason. Thank you!  If you rewrite your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @cjkeilig, I have read this and similar posts before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as wOxxOm said, the problem concerned in presence of the breakpoints, preceding the first access to chrome ([crbug.com/754976](http://crbug.com/754976))